# TextView ContextMenu

Tags: java, android, xml

I want to create a TextView and when I click on it, a small menu will apear, which I can use to change color of the text. I made this, but when I try to click TextView, no menu shows up. What should I change to make it work?

MainActivity

```
package com.example.menu;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

import android.content.res.ColorStateList;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.ActionMode;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    MenuItem pozadi1,pozadi2,pozadi3,pozadi4;
    RelativeLayout pozadi;
    TextView styl;
    TextView barva;
    MenuItem red,blue,green;
    MenuItem normalni,tucne,kurziva;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        pozadi = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.pozadi);
        pozadi1 = (MenuItem) findViewById(R.id.pozadi1);
        pozadi2 = (MenuItem) findViewById(R.id.pozadi2);
        pozadi3 = (MenuItem) findViewById(R.id.pozadi3);
        pozadi4 = (MenuItem) findViewById(R.id.pozadi4);
        styl = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.styl);
        barva = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.barva);
        red = (MenuItem) findViewById(R.id.red);
        blue = (MenuItem) findViewById(R.id.blue);
        green = (MenuItem) findViewById(R.id.green);
        normalni = (MenuItem) findViewById(R.id.normal);
        tucne = (MenuItem) findViewById(R.id.tucne);
        kurziva = (MenuItem) findViewById(R.id.kurziva);

        registerForContextMenu(barva);

    }
    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
        new MenuInflater(this).inflate(R.menu.menubarva,menu);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.blue:
                barva.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
                return true;
            case R.id.green:
                barva.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
                return true;
            case R.id.red:
                barva.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
    //KOD NA ZMĚNU POZADÍ
      //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
   @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        new MenuInflater(this).inflate(R.menu.menu1,menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu((Menu) menu);
    }
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
        switch(item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.pozadi1:
                pozadi.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pozadi1);break;
            case R.id.pozadi2:
                pozadi.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pozadi2);break;
            case R.id.pozadi3:
                pozadi.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pozadi3);break;
            case R.id.pozadi4:
                pozadi.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pozadi4);break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
}
```

activity_main.xml. I think there is no problem

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/pozadi">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:text="Změna typu písma"
        android:layout_marginTop="100sp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/styl"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:text="Změna barvy písma"
        android:layout_marginTop="250sp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/barva"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is an XML with colors, same, I think there is no problem.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/red"
        android:title="Červená"/>

    <item android:id="@+id/blue"
        android:title="ˇModrá"/>

    <item android:id="@+id/green"
        android:title="Zelená"/>
</menu>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a my project:
[GitHub](https://github.com/Gabriele-P03/GreenLand/blob/d3981968045e17f72255b0772db09a5e7a0cfcb0/app/src/main/java/com/greenland/MainActivity.java#L97)

Take a look at showSeedInfo() method.

First call the onClickListener about TextView, then with a lambda call your method(similar to mine) which display the layout inflated

```
private void showSeedInfo() {

    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.seed_read_popup, null);

    Seed seed = loadSettings.getSeed();

    int[] rcmdValues = new int[]{seed.getTemperature()[0], seed.getTemperature()[1],
            seed.getHumidity()[0], seed.getHumidity()[1],
            seed.getLight()[0], seed.getLight()[1]};

    Button button = popupView.findViewById(R.id.updateSeedButton);
    button.setOnClickListener(v -> BluetoothActivity.bltSocket.updateSeed(rcmdValues));

    TextView name = popupView.findViewById(R.id.namePlantView);
    name.setText(seed.getNamePlant());
    TextView temperature = popupView.findViewById(R.id.temperaturePlantView);
    temperature.setText(rcmdValues[0] + "-" + rcmdValues[1]);
    TextView humidity = popupView.findViewById(R.id.humidityPlantView);
    humidity.setText(rcmdValues[2] + "-" + rcmdValues[3]);
    TextView light = popupView.findViewById(R.id.lightPlantView);
    light.setText(rcmdValues[4] + "-" + rcmdValues[5]);

    int size = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
    final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView, size, size, true);
    popupWindow.showAtLocation(popupView, Gravity.CENTER, size, size);
}
```

Comment: Hi, so I've added setOnClickListener on TextView, but I am kinda new to programming and I don't know what you mean with lambda call. I think you mean I should somehow take the part onCreateContextMenu and onContextItemSelected and put in inside OnClick ? Thank you for your help!

Comment: First do not use onContextmenu(). Find your text view via findViewById(int id) then set the listener via TextView#setOnClickListener().

Comment: About the lambda, that's the basic of Java... Before program Android app, please learn java

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try onClickListener
public View.OnClickListener mClickListener = new View.OnClickListener()
public void onClick(View v)
}
};